# rotation of a point in 3D about an arbitrary axis using python

Tags: python

If I have a point in 3D `(x,y,z)` and I need to rotate this point about an arbitrary axis that passes through two points `(x1,y1,z1)` and `(x2,y2,z2)` with an angle theta counterclockwise, how can I do this using python?

I read a lot about 3D rotation, but I failed to make it using python, so please can anybody help?

Comment: Well, can you describe the formula in mathematical notation? I don't think it's so much of a python related question, but pure math.

Comment: You should familiarize yourself with the physics, but here is a nice blog post about 3D movement.  The author likes C++, but I'm sure you can figure out how to apply the ideas.  http://gafferongames.com/game-physics/physics-in-3d/

Answer (score 7):

Okay, it's been long enough that i'm getting notificaations that i didn't do this properly. Please see a corrected version below.

[image]

Getting the unit vector's easy, then just do the matrix multiplication.

```
import numpy as np

def matrix_multiply(*matrices):
    if len(matrices) == 1:
        return matrices
    else:
        try:
            m_other = matrix_multiply(*matrices[1:])
            return np.matmul(matrices[0], m_other)
        except:
            print(matrices[0])
            print(m_other)
            raise

def R(p, x1, x2, theta):
    p = [[pp] for pp in p + [1]]
    x1, y1, z1 = x1
    x2, y2, z2 = x2

    U = [x2-x1, y2-y1, z2-z1]
    U = np.array(U) / np.sqrt(np.dot(U,U))
    a,b,c = U
    d = np.sqrt(b**2 + c**2)

    T = [[1,0,0,-x1],[0,1,0,-y1],[0,0,1,-z1],[0,0,0,1]]
    T_inv = [[1,0,0,x1],[0,1,0,y1],[0,0,1,z1],[0,0,0,1]]

    R_x = [[1,0,0,0],[0,c/d,-b/d,0],[0,b/d,c/d,0],[0,0,0,1]]
    R_x_inv = [[1,0,0,0],[0,c/d,b/d,0],[0,-b/d,c/d,0],[0,0,0,1]]

    R_y = [[d,0,-a,0],[0,1,0,0],[a,0,d,0],[0,0,0,1]]
    R_y_inv = [[d,0,a,0],[0,1,0,0],[-a,0,d,0],[0,0,0,1]]

    ct = np.cos(theta)
    st = np.sin(theta)
    R_z = [[ct,st,0,0],[-st,ct,0,0],[0,0,1,0],[0,0,0,1]]

    p2 = matrix_multiply(T_inv, R_x_inv, R_y_inv, R_z, R_y, R_x, T, p)
    return p2[0][:3]

x1 = [1,1,0]
x2 = [1,0,1]

p = [0,0,0]

p2 = R(p, x1, x2, np.pi)
print(p2)
```

That should work now. [try it out here](https://www.online-python.com/GTsComvi0L).

Comment: This answer gives the matrix for rotations about an axis through the origin, not an arbitrary axis as asked for in the question.  The correct matrix is given at https://sites.google.com/site/glennmurray/Home/rotation-matrices-and-formulas.

Comment: I just add that if you are interested in the above matrix, remember to correct a few typos! First and third columns of the second row and second column of the third row.

Comment: Confirmed Glenn's statement. This code does not work as advertised. Odd too, since you pass in both points for the unit vector...but then don't use them...

Comment: If you want to rotate about an arbitrary axis *not* passing through the origin, then you can still use this, you just have to translate the point before and after.

Comment: @Glenn Dead link

Comment: @Glenn i have finally fixed it.

Comment: @Reinderien no need for the link anymore, i've fixed it.

Comment: Here's an updated link to the correct formulas.  https://sites.google.com/site/glennmurray/glenn-murray-ph-d/rotation-matrices-and-formulas

Answer (score 5):

I would look at the simple Python library by Chris Gohlke: [transformations](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/code/transformations.py.html).  He includes many examples embedded within the source code.  Good luck.